# tf.MonitoredSession accessing raw session without hooks: run_step_fn vs _tf_sess

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tf.MonitoredSession, it happens sometimes that you want to evaluate some nodes but you don't want to proceed in the training step, so you do not want to use the Hooks to log stuffs.
It seems that the session is wrapped several times and the raw session is stored in a nested way: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8425
but it can also be retrieved with method _tf_sess() https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11971

To recap I think there are two possible ways to run without hooks:

1. use step_fn https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MonitoredSession#run_step_fn
2. access the raw session with `raw_session = sess._tf_sess()`

I think way 2. is the more intuitive for me if I want to be free from the hooks, but is it proper practice are there some problems in doing this?
I wonder why is it private and it is not contemplated to have a method to access the raw session like in `SingularMonitoredSession.raw_session()`? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SingularMonitoredSession

 
At line 1010 in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.11/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py I can see that raw_session is defined exactly returning self._tf_sess(), so I wonder why the explicit choice to not have the user the possibility to access the raw session in MonitoredSession, is it possible to incur in some problems using sess._tf_sess()?
  I wonder if it has something to do with some problems in the distributed setting..

Comment: Now also a feature request: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23403